# Parse Robots.txt in python and check for http status code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having some Problems parsing robots.txt in python.
I want to store each line of the robots.txt in an array, which is working at the moment.

Afterwards I want to check for the url and each value in the array (which will be an unique URL), which status code I receive when I request the Page. 
For Example we have the value "/abc" in the array and the url is "https://stackoverflow.com". I then want to check the URL "https://stackoverflow.com/abc" for the http status code and print it out.

The Code I got so far is:

```
import os
import os
import io
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib.error



#Command to Use User Input as URL:
#url = input("Input Url" + '\n')

url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt'
raw_robots = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
robots= raw_robots.read().decode('utf-8')
result_data_set = {"Disallowed":[], "Allowed":[]}

for line in robots.split("\n"):
    if line.startswith('Allow'):    # this is for allowed url
        result_data_set["Allowed"].append(line.split(': ')[1].split(' ')[0])    # to neglect the comments or other junk info
    elif line.startswith('Disallow'):    # this is for disallowed url
        result_data_set["Disallowed"].append(line.split(': ')[1].split(' ')[0])    # to neglect the comments or other junk info

print (result_data_set)

url2 = 'https://stackoverflow.com'

for x in result_data_set:
    try:
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url2+x)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    # Return code error (e.g. 404, 501, ...)
    # ...
        print('HTTPError: {}'.format(e.code))
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    # Not an HTTP-specific error (e.g. connection refused)
    # ...
        print('URLError: {}'.format(e.reason))
    else:
    # 200
    # ...
        print(x+'good')
```

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: I do not see any error messages .. thats the problem :/

Comment: do you see result_data_set printed? If that was empty, your loop won't execute.

Comment: Yes, it does get printed.